# Including text and variable in rep() for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, rep

Having some trouble trying to assign classifiers to my data. I have 500 rows of data, and I'd like to assign "City 1", "City 2", etc... up to "City 50". And repeat each one 10 times. So it should have "City 1" 10 times, and then "City 2" 10 times, until "City 50" 10 times. Where I'm struggling is having text in quotes as well as a variable call in the same argument of rep().

```
for (j in 1:50)
{
City<-rep(paste("City",j),1,each=10)
}
```

My output for this is just simply a list of "City 50" 10 times. I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

Comment: Damn, made it way more complicated than I had to. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `rep` and `paste` are both vectorized, this can be done without any loop

```
rep(paste("City", 1:50), each = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

akrun is correct in that is an easier way to do what you want. but if you want to keep the loop, you have to index City by City[j] when assigning values. what's happening is your loop is running correctly as written. the output you're seeing is the last iteration. in the way your loop is written (without indexing City) you are replacing the value of city for every value of j